# How can I use GNU gettext with VB6?

Tags: vb6, localization, internationalization, gettext

I've been using gettext in several private projects and now I want to use gettext to translate strings of a Visual Basic 6 application.

I've checked the GNU gettext packages and it seems that I have to write quite some boilerplate code to get it working with VB6 and I fear that my boss won't allow it.

- Is there some out-of-the box package for VB6? (Something like dxgettext would be a dream!)
- Have you done something similar?
- Is it even possible?
- Where do I start?

Answer (score 0):

See [VB Language Manager Pro.](http://www.whippleware.com/vblm.htm)

Designed to do precisely what you want -- extract, translate, and replace all the strings in a VB6 app.

Whippleware products work.

A caveat; Ben Whipple is probably not actively marketing these products anymore, since VB6 is not mainstream.  It may take some patience to get a copy of the software.